# Can USB-C be restricted for display only (i.e. no data transfer)?

Tags: windows, usb, windows-permissions

I want to allow users to connect their company mobile phones to company tablets for display only using USB-C. These are windows tablets.

Is there anyway of restricting the USB-C to only allow display? Is there anything that can be enforced via  Group policy?

I don't want unauthorised devices to connect to the company tablets via USB-C.